# How to change text color in excel using custom formatting in formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I am combining few cells to make a report which needs to be sent my team daily. The cells has both positive and negative values and I need to show negative in RED color.

I tried below formula but it doesn't work

```
=A8&TEXT(F8,"0.0%;[Red]0.0%")
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Can you edit and post a sample of your data?

Comment: A formula will not set the format of a cell.  It will output a number format as a text string, but that does not change the format of the cell itself.  A formula will not change the color of the text.  The formats allowed are limited to simple formats.

Comment: The best thing would be to put A8 in one cell and align it right and put the amounts in the next cell alligned left with your desired format, then remove the lines.

Answer (score -1):

Check if this can solve your problem: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/10/excel-conditional-formatting-formulas/#conditional-formatting-using-formulas

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks unfortunately this not what I am looking for. I need some thing which will work in formula of a cell.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Well, there is mostly explained in screenshots, I thought it make a real clutter if I post them here.